# Unread mail in folder cascading in outlook 2007

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007

In outlook 2007 i like to keep all my emails very organised so i have ended up with quite a bit of folder cascading. Its great when i start going through all the email that i know where it all is but the big problem is the unread count does not "cascade down the tree".

For instance if i have my folders like this:

- Logs (20)

  - Failed logs (100)
  - Timeout Logs (50)

I want to be able to see 170 in logs instead of just 20.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuantely I'm pretty sure there is no way to do this in outlook currently.

Answer (score 1):

How about using search folders as the "sub folders"

Answer (score 1):

Upvote for JS and search folders.  I can't comment yet. :(

Search folders will give you the count of items meeting the criteria.  In my case I have a search folder for backup failures.  Any customer with a back up failure meets the search criteria and I can see at a glance the number of failure emails.